# How to Add Placeholder on TextView Object in PyGObject

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, pygobject

I've added placeholder on `Entry` object:

```
self._widget = Gtk.Entry()
self._widget.set_placeholder_text("Enter your name")
```

Now I want to add placeholder on `TextView` object, but I didn't find any method for it:

```
self._widget = Gtk.TextView()
```

Comment: Gtk.Textview does not have a placeholder nor related methods

Comment: @JoséFonte yes, but i'm looking for a way to implement it.

Comment: The question is not so clear. Well, ain't easy to implement the behavior of the placeholder. Maybe by using different textbuffers and using signals to swap the buffers.

Comment: I have had the same use case. Not sure why the gtk-devs provided this by default for gtk-entry but not for textview. My use case is "exam question flip-cards" with one question on one side, you flip it, the answer is shown. I want to provide additional hints to the first-time user how to use it, so placeholder text would be useful. (I already also use tooltips and pop-over widgets, but users are different. Some need more help than others. I differ between first-time starting the widget, and continued use of course.)  Would be convenient if more widgets in gtk3 could have that work as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect to `focus-in-event` and `focus-out-event`. If the text buffer is empty on `focus-out-event`, set a placeholder flag to true, add the placeholder text, and add a CSS class that you can optionally use to style the placeholder text gray. If the placeholder flag is true on `focus-in-event`, empty the text buffer, and remove the CSS class.