# How to set Placeholder text in Gtk.TextView

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, gtkentry, gtktextview

I have been using Gtk Entry till now which offers set_placeholder_text method to set a placeholder text in it however, looking in the documentation , I found no such method for TextView .

Is there any way I can set placeholder text in Gtk Textview ?

Comment: there isn't a method in Gtk.TextView similar to the one in Gtk.Entry. You'll have to implement it by yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add Placeholder on TextView Object in PyGObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715457/how-to-add-placeholder-on-textview-object-in-pygobject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there was a question almost similar to this one. The idea is to, eg, use the `focus-in-event` and `focus-out-event` to check the text buffer content.

Example:

1. Set placeholder text as a variable
2. Set the placeholder text as the default treeview text buffer
   content
3. On focus in, if the text buffer equals the placeholder, means no
   previous input, so delete the text (placeholder text). Otherwise
   keep the content.
4. On focus out, if the text buffer has no text then set the content
   as the placeholder text. Otherwise do nothing.

The idea is that if no text or the existing text is the placeholder text it means there's no user input.

**Python example**

Glade ui file (save it as placeholder-textview.ui):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkTextBuffer" id="textbuffer1">
    <property name="text" translatable="yes">Please input text here...</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="placeholder_text" translatable="yes">This is an entry and below is a textview</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTextView" id="textview1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="vexpand">False</property>
                <property name="buffer">textbuffer1</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Python code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


def onFocusIn(self, event):
    if (textbuf.get_text(textbuf.get_start_iter(), textbuf.get_end_iter(), True) == placeholderStr):
        textbuf.set_text("")
    return False


def onFocusOut(self, event):
    if (textbuf.get_text(textbuf.get_start_iter(), textbuf.get_end_iter(), True) == ""):
        textbuf.set_text(placeholderStr)
    return False

placeholderStr = "This is the placeholder text..."

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("placeholder-textview.ui")

window = builder.get_object("window1")

textbuf = builder.get_object("textbuffer1")
textbuf.set_text(placeholderStr)

textview = builder.get_object("textview1")
textview.connect("focus-in-event", onFocusIn)
textview.connect("focus-out-event", onFocusOut)

window.connect ("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Resulting UI:

[image]

Added a few widgets to keep the initial focus on other widgets.

Compare the behavior with the Gtk.Entry. It's very similar.